# RNA to Protein simulation program's TypeErorr?

Tags: python, string, list, function, typeerror

Here's what I'm doing:

```
def dna_complement(dna):
  coup = ""
  for letter in dna:
    if letter == "C":
      coup += "G"
    if letter == "G":
      coup += "C"
    if letter == "A":
      coup += "T"
    if letter == "T":
      coup += "A"
  return coup
  

def convert_to_rna(dna):
  coup2 = ""
  for letter in dna:
    if letter == "C":
      coup2 += "G"
    if letter == "G":
      coup2 += "C"
    if letter == "A":
      coup2 += "U"
    if letter == "T":
      coup2 += "A"
  return coup2

def translate(rna):
  amino_acid = ""
  for len in rna:
    if range(0, len(rna), 3) == "UUU" :
      amino_acid = CODON_TABLE.get("UUU")
    if range(0, len(rna), 3) == "UUC" :
      amino_acid = CODON_TABLE.get("UUC")
    if range(0, len(rna), 3) == "UUA" :
      amino_acid = CODON_TABLE.get("UUA")
  


CODON_TABLE = {'UUU':'Phe','UUC':'Phe','UUA':'Leu','UUG':'Leu','CUU':'Leu','CUC':'Leu','CUA':'Leu','CUG':'Leu','AUU':'Ile','AUC':'Ile','AUA':'Ile','AUG':'Met','GUU':'Val','GUC':'Val','GUA':'Val','GUG':'Val','UCU':'Ser','UCC':'Ser','UCA':'Ser','UCG':'Ser','CCU':'Pro','CCC':'Pro','CCA':'Pro','CCG':'Pro','ACU':'Thr','ACC':'Thr','ACA':'Thr','ACG':'Thr','GCU':'Ala','GCC':'Ala','GCA':'Ala','GCG':'Ala','UAU':'Tyr','UAC':'Tyr','UAA':'STOP','UAG':'STOP','CAU':'His','CAC':'His','CAA':'Gln','CAG':'Gln','AAU':'Asn','AAC':'Asn','AAA':'Lys','AAG':'Lys','GAU':'Asp','GAC':'Asp','GAA':'Glu','GAG':'Glu','UGU':'Cys','UGC':'Cys','UGA':'STOP','UGG':'Trp','CGU':'Arg','CGC':'Arg','CGA':'Arg','CGG':'Arg','AGU':'Ser','AGC':'Ser','AGA':'Arg','AGG':'Arg','GGU':'Gly','GGC':'Gly','GGA':'Gly','GGG':'Gly'}

""" the rna is "UUCUCUACGGUAACAGGGGGCCGGAGGACGACGACGAGAAUCGCCCCGGUGUAGCCGGUGGCGACGGGACGGGGACCUCCCACCGGGGUGGCCGGCAAUGUCGCUCGUAUG" # This is already converted from DNA to RNA so there's no worry about the original RNA
"""

dna="AAGAGATGCCATTGTCCCCCGGCCTCCTGCTGCTGCTCTTAGCGGGGCCACATCGGCCACCGCTGCCCTGCCCCTGGAGGGTGGCCCCACCGGCCGTTACAGCGAGCATAC" 

def main():
  print("\nWelcome to the DNA program: The Code of Life.")
  print("\nSample DNA strand:\n")
  print("Regular DNA:")
  print_bases(dna)
  print("DNA after complement: ")
  dna2 = dna_complement(dna)
  print_bases(dna2)
  print("DNA after RNA convertion: ")
  rna = convert_to_rna(dna)
  print_bases(rna)
  print("The result of translation: ")
  amino_acid = translate(rna)
  print(amino_acid)
```

As in the image above. (Thanks to a user called Random Davis telling me to correct my mistake on the description, now I have everything I'm having right now in display which might be a little better)

When I tried to run this the Type Error telling me that str object is not callable, can someone help me with this?

More information: Sorry for not saying this earlier, I was trying to get the conversion like UUU <-> Phe, UUA <-> Leu, and AUU <-> Ile. And stop the protein from generating once it detected UAA, UAG, UGA.

Comment: `for len in rna` is the issue; you're seemingly overwriting the name `len` with a string, and then trying to call `len`. Never shadow a built-in name, because this is the exact issue you'll run into. Also it's really unhelpful if you tell us you have an error but not post the full stacktrace or indicate where the error happened; it forces us unnecessarily to play a guessing game to figure out where the error might be happening.

Comment: @Random Davis Alright, lemme change it really quick

Comment: Bit unclear how you identify an amino acid. Is it from the first codon found in the RNA?

Comment: @Jack Deeth Hi there! The thing we use to identify a amino acid is the RNA!

Comment: So, is `rna = "UUCUCU"` meant to be `PheSer` or `PheSerLeuSer`? Do the letters only get used once?

Comment: @JackDeeth Uh, it should say "Phe Ser"

Comment: Brilliant, that's clear! The good news is you don't need to write `if (something) == “UUU":` for every codon because python dictionaries can do this for you :)

Comment: Thank you! Be right back for testing! Hope you're having a nice day!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241883/discussion-between-kl777-and-jack-deeth).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you turn the whole RNA string into a codon string:

```py
CODON_TABLE = {'UUU':'Phe','UUC':'Phe','UUA':'Leu','UUG':'Leu','CUU':'Leu','CUC':'Leu'} # etc

def translate(rna):
    amino_acid = ""
    for i in range(len(rna)-2):
        three_letter = rna[i:i+3]
        if three_letter in CODON_TABLE:
            amino_acid += CODON_TABLE[three_letter]
            # if a match is found, don't look for a new codon starting with
            # the second or third letter of this codon
            i += 2 
        return amino_acid
```

---

Explanation:
`for i in range(len(rna)-2):` will give us an index number to the parts of the RNA string we want to read:

```
UUCUCUAC   len = 8
012345      i = 0-5 = range(6)
```

`rna[i:i+3]` gives us the three letters starting from the `i`th one

```
UUCUCUAC  = rna
UUC       i = 0, three_letter = rna[0:3]
 UCU      i = 1, tl = rna[1:4]
  CUC     i = 2, tl = rna[2:5]
   UCU    i = 3, tl = rna[3:6]
    CUA   i = 4, tl = rna[4:7]
     UAC  i = 5, tl = rna[5:8]
```

For each three-letter sequence, if it's a codon, it adds the name of the codon to the amino acid

```py
amino_acid += CODON_TABLE[three_letter]
```

Then it skips `i` forward by 2 to avoid looking for another codon starting with letters we've already used:

```
UUCUCUAC
UUC       Phe
 UCU      (skip)
  CUC     (skip)
   UCU    Ser
    CUA   (skip)
     UAC  (skip)
```

If it finds something that's not a codon, it ignores it and moves onto the next three letters. (I'm not a biologist, I don't know if every three-letter sequence is a codon?)

```
UUCZUCUAC
UUC        Phe
 UCU       (skip)
  CUC      (skip)
   ZUC     (not found)
    UCU    Sre
```

Comment: Thanks for willing to help, be right back! I'll test and tell you the result soon!

Comment: why -3 instead of -2 in the range?

len("abc") is 3, len("abc") - 3 is 0, range(0) is empty...

Comment: @gabriel that was a typo :)

Comment: Well, I'd say it somehow worked. Now I'm trying to figure out how to get the following proteins showing up. Could you provide me some more details?

Comment: off by 1 problems, programmer's day to day mortal enemies

Comment: @GabrielPellegrino Yeah...programming sure is challenging

Comment: It seems to be working perfectly! Now what I have to figure out now is to how to separate each 3-letter terms with spaces and telling them to stop when they meet the UAA, UAG, or UGA!

Comment: @KL777 I see that you are new to stackoverflow, but that's not really how the platform is meant to be used. You faced a strange error that you weren't aware of, you made your post. Now you have new challenges that aren't even related to your initial question. Time to move on from this question, mark answers as correct.

Sadly, the truth is that we are not here to solve your entire problem, but to help you punctually.

Answer (score 1):

I would first rewrite your

```
range(0, len(rna), 3)
```

Do you want to get 3 by 3 from your input? For example, if your input is "ABCDE", first you want "ABC", then you want "BCD", etc. Is that correct?

If so, I would do it like this:

```
p = rna[i:i+3]
```

where rna is your input string.

Also, what do you want to do if you found UUU, UUC or UUA? What if you find all of them?

I hope you find this helpful.

```
def translate(rna):
  amino_acid = []
  for i in range(len(rna) - 2):
    p = rna[i:i+3]
    if p == "UUU" :
      amino_acid.append(CODON_TABLE["UUU"])
    if p == "UUC" :
      amino_acid.append(CODON_TABLE["UUC"])
    if p == "UUA" :
      amino_acid.append(CODON_TABLE["UUA"])
  
  return amino_acid

CODON_TABLE = {'UUU':'Phe','UUC':'Phe','UUA':'Leu','UUG':'Leu','CUU':'Leu','CUC':'Leu','CUA':'Leu','CUG':'Leu','AUU':'Ile','AUC':'Ile','AUA':'Ile','AUG':'Met','GUU':'Val','GUC':'Val','GUA':'Val','GUG':'Val','UCU':'Ser','UCC':'Ser','UCA':'Ser','UCG':'Ser','CCU':'Pro','CCC':'Pro','CCA':'Pro','CCG':'Pro','ACU':'Thr','ACC':'Thr','ACA':'Thr','ACG':'Thr','GCU':'Ala','GCC':'Ala','GCA':'Ala','GCG':'Ala','UAU':'Tyr','UAC':'Tyr','UAA':'STOP','UAG':'STOP','CAU':'His','CAC':'His','CAA':'Gln','CAG':'Gln','AAU':'Asn','AAC':'Asn','AAA':'Lys','AAG':'Lys','GAU':'Asp','GAC':'Asp','GAA':'Glu','GAG':'Glu','UGU':'Cys','UGC':'Cys','UGA':'STOP','UGG':'Trp','CGU':'Arg','CGC':'Arg','CGA':'Arg','CGG':'Arg','AGU':'Ser','AGC':'Ser','AGA':'Arg','AGG':'Arg','GGU':'Gly','GGC':'Gly','GGA':'Gly','GGG':'Gly'}

rna = "UUCUCUACGGUAACAGGGGGCCGGAGGACGACGACGAGAAUCGCCCCGGUGUAGCCGGUGGCGACGGGACGGGGACCUCCCACCGGGGUGGCCGGCAAUGUCGCUCGUAUG" # This is already converted from DNA to RNA so there's no worry about the original RNA

translate(rna)
```

Notice that I am iterating over the input and ignoring the last two characters, that's the reason why we iterate till range(len(rna)-2).

Comment: Be right back real quick! Anyway, thanks for coming to help Mr.Gabriel!

Comment: Sorry, but, no. I was trying to get the conversion like  UUU to Phe, UUG to Leu, things like that. Anyway thanks for helping me realize my mistake, I'll go edit the question right now for more clear information!

Comment: What happens if the input RNA contains both UUU and UUC? You want Phe Phe or only Phe? What if it contains UUU and UUA, you want Phe Leu?

Comment: Let me double check real quick! Be right back!

Comment: Ah yes the output I wanted is the Phe Phe! And if the UUU and UUA exists in a same time it should be Phe Leu!

Comment: Updated it to contain this new requirement. What if the input rna contains CUU?

Comment: Uh, the list works... just sadly that's not what I really wanted ;)